# Dealing with breadcrumbs in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, breadcrumbs, laravel-blade

I have simple breadcrumbs on my page

```
<ul class="breadcrumb"> 
<li> 
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> 
         <a href="{{URL::to('/') }}">Home</a> 
    </li> 
    <?php $link = URL::to('/'); ?> 
    @for($i = 1; $i <= count(Request::segments()); $i++) 
        <li> 
            @if($i < count(Request::segments()) & $i > 0) 
                <?php $link .= "/" . Request::segment($i); ?> 
                    <a href="<?= $link ?>">{{Request::segment($i)}}</a> 
            @else {{Request::segment($i)}} 
            @endif 
</li> 
    @endfor 
</ul>
```

This produce breadcrumbs like `Home / Page / etc`

The problem here is that I have views in my router is like this

```
Route::get('/users/profile', ['uses' => 'UsersController@viewProfile', 'before' => 'auth|csrf']);
Route::get ('/admin/pages/edit/{pageId}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@pageEdit', 'before' => 'admin']);
```

So for both routes breadcrumbs will be

```
Home / Users / Profile
Home / Admin / Pages / Edit / 1
```

Here middle path in breadcrumb is not existing in this case `/ Users /` and `/ Edit /` .. There are a lot pages like this. Is there a way to avoid this?

Edit:

I know I just can change routes in my router but I don't want. So need some other way to achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

You can [use this](https://github.com/sina-rzp/laravel-simple-breadcrumb), and then add a condition (line 24) that:

```
@if ($title != 'Users' && $title != 'Edit')
    <a href="{{ $bread }}"><span>{{ $title }}</span></a>
@endif
```

Alternatively, if you have lots of these values that you would like to avoid, then you can write an `array` and check them with the same approach.